# Best practice MySQL Server migration

Tags: mysql, server, migration

we have currently reached a point with our setup, that I would like to move our database server (mysql) to a seperate machine. That way it should be easier to create a "database cloud" later at some point.

Currently everything is on 1 server. Our php applications, apis and some other stuff. Unfortunatly (as always) it's not documented to the best. I would love to avoid as much down time as possible and I am not really sure I know all the apps running on the server which I would have to change.

My idea was to setup a standalone mysql server and create a master <-> master replication with the current server and let them both run parallel for a month or 2. That way I can ensure uptime while I switch alle the applications to the new database server.

I've already set up a test master <-> master setup with 2 virtual machines (ain't running perfectly yet but I will get there)

But now I just wanted to ask out, how you guys do this kind of migration before I actually start changing the currents server configs.

Many thanks in advance!

Thomas